# File upload And View Not Working in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating MVC application i have using Entity framework. finally want create  File upload and View . i have Controller Project Controller To file upload

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> FileManager(int ProjectId = 0)
    {
        ReadCookieValue cookie = new ReadCookieValue();

        clientId = cookie.readuserinfo().ClientId;
        userId = cookie.readuserinfo().Id;
        roleId = cookie.readuserinfo().RoleId;
        var model = await _project.FilesList(ProjectId, clientId);
        return View(model);
    }
    public async Task<ActionResult> FileUpload(int ProjectId = 0)
    {
        return View(ProjectId);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> FileUploadHandler(int ProjectId = 0)
    {
        ReadCookieValue cookie = new ReadCookieValue();

        clientId = cookie.readuserinfo().ClientId;
        userId = cookie.readuserinfo().Id;
        roleId = cookie.readuserinfo().RoleId;
        if (ProjectId != 0)
        {
            foreach (var fileKey in Request.Files.AllKeys)
            {
                ProjectFileModel model = null;
                var file = Request.Files[fileKey];
                try
                {
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        model = new ProjectFileModel();
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), clientId.ToString(), ProjectId.ToString());
                        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                        }
                        var path1 = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                        model.ProjectId = ProjectId;
                        model.FileName = fileName;
                        model.FilePath = path;
                        model.UploadedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                        model.UploadedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        model.ClientId = clientId;
                        var result = await _project.UploadFiles(model);
                        file.SaveAs(path1);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Message = "Please Select Project" });
        }
        return Json(new { Message = "File saved" });
    }
```

after i create project  i have View button  to open upload file.click view button  i  getting  error

```
 {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
 Inner Exception  null
```

actually i am using Entity framework model  and  am using  own model.

File upload code

```
   <div class="ibox-content">
<ng-form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="@Url.Action("FileUploadHandler", "Projects")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit this form!</button>
  </ng-form>

  </div>
```

here using FileUploadHandler controller Action.Here FileuploadHandler  code

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> FileUploadHandler(int ProjectId = 0)
        {
            ReadCookieValue cookie = new ReadCookieValue();

            clientId = cookie.readuserinfo().ClientId;
            userId = cookie.readuserinfo().Id;
            roleId = cookie.readuserinfo().RoleId;
            if (ProjectId != 0)
            {
                foreach (var fileKey in Request.Files.AllKeys)
                {
                    ProjectFileModel model = null;
                    var file = Request.Files[fileKey];
                    try
                    {
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            model = new ProjectFileModel();
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), clientId.ToString(), ProjectId.ToString());
                            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                            }
                            var path1 = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                            model.ProjectId = ProjectId;
                            model.FileName = fileName;
                            model.FilePath = path;
                            model.UploadedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                            model.UploadedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            model.ClientId = clientId;
                            var result = await _project.UploadFiles(model);
                            file.SaveAs(path1);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Please Select Project" });
            }
            return Json(new { Message = "File saved" });
        }
```

previous this code develop with out Entity framework. after take this created entity framework model  i have seen two model  type of class i can seen edmx under  model folder and

```
 namespace Inspinia_MVC5.Entityframework
{
    using System;

    public partial class ProjectsList_Result
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Employees { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnalyticsStart { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnalyticsEnd { get; set; }
        public string ReportType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have Follow previous method inside of Entity Framework   without entity framework model type

```
 namespace Inspinia_MVC5.Models
{
    public class ProjectsModel
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public List<LoginModelViewModel> AllEmployees { get; set; }
        public string Employees { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnalyticsStart { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnalyticsEnd { get; set; }
        public List<ReportType> reportTypes { get; set; }
        public string ReportType { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in my Solution folder i  have seen `App_start/Uploads/1/1`    . when i run the code getting Error

```
  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
     Inner Exception  null
```

please anyone tell me what mistake i did? please anyone help out of this issues?

Comment: Have you used the debugger on the server to see what is null? It could be the cookie? Well it could be anything!

Comment: can i use entity model and my own model  at a same time?

Comment: Yes, in what sense? Are you using Visual Studio? Debugging with Local Host should stop when the exception is thrown, then you can inspect the null element. That is the info we need :)

Comment: Employee Value not passing ..but before i create project that time Employee value coming

Comment: Are you referring to this line: `clientId = cookie.readuserinfo().ClientId;`? I don't think your problem is related to Entity Framework at all.

Comment: I am using Entityframework model and my own model . yes i refer this line  clientId = cookie.readuserinfo().ClientId;

Comment: You have some cookie issues then, that has nothing to do with Entity Framework. That is related to the way you browser is talking to the web server. I am not someone who can help with that. I suggest you create a new question with more appropriate tags aiming at the `ReadCookieValue` not returning correct values.

Comment: You need to check whether the file has any data - you can read and create a File object even if no file was uploaded.

Answer (score -1):

File Upload:- I am showing you take a example how to write code for upload file

Suppose I am uploading file in video Table and using PostVideo Model

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult PostAVideo(PostVideo model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = "/Uploads/" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserName + "/" + model.Category;
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(filePath)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(filePath));
            }

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(filePath), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            Video _model = new Video();
            _model.Title = model.Title;
            _model.Path = filePath + "/" + fileName;
            _model.Keyword = model.Keyword;
            _model.Description = model.Description;
            _model.Categories = model.Category;
            _model.CreatedDate = model.CreatedDate;
            _model.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            _model.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            _model.Name = fileName;
            _model.IsDownload = model.IsDownload;
            _model.IsCommented = model.IsComment;
            _model.Poster = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
            db.Video.Add(_model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();


        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer would benefit greatly from explaining *why* you should do things this way, and how it differs from the code in the question.